# JavaScript/Underscore delete array based on object property inside a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

My array looks like this

```
var array = [
  {
    "name" : "abc",
    "items" : [
       {
         "name": "def"
         "url" : "https://"
       },
       {
         "name": "jkl"
         "url" : "http://"
       }
    ]
  },
  {
   "name" : "ghi",
   "items" : [
      {
         "name": "jkl"
         "url" : "http://"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How would i delete the object 'jkl' inside 'abc' preferably using underscore

Comment: What is your expected output, and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var array = [
  {
    "name" : "abc",
    "items" : [
       {
         "name": "def",
         "url" : "https://"
       },
       {
         "name": "jkl",
         "url" : "http://"
       }
    ]
  },
  {
   "name" : "ghi",
   "items" : [
      {
         "name": "jkl",
         "url" : "http://"
      }
    ]
  }
]

console.log("Array before = ",array);

array = array.map( elem => {
   if(elem.name !== "abc") return elem;
   elem.items = elem.items.filter(item => item.name !== "jkl" );
   return elem;
})

console.log("Array after = ",array);
```